# Cartodbfying and using ghost tables in CartoDB Enterprise?

Tags: postgis, carto

I'm using Carto Enterprise, and I need help on making custom DB tables show up in Carto builder page when you log in.
So far I've turned ON the ghost_tables feature like this.

```
/opt/carto/builder-tools/embedded/bin/carto-builder-feature-flags.sh enable all ghost_tables
```

I've also created a table and used cartodbfy.

```
curl -v -k -X GET https://username.carto.com/user/mbpskt/api/v2/sql?q='CREATE+TABLE+usertable+(+cartodb_id+INTEGER+)'&api_key='key'

SELECT cdb_cartodbfytable('username','username.usertable');
```

After cartodbfying, it will create the_geom and the_geom_webmercator columns, but it just NEVER shows up in the builder screen.

I think I've done everything possible, but it just doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: If you are a CARTO customer using the enterprise offering you should contact support@carto.com instead, where they will be able to give you more in-depth assistance.

Comment: Polygeo why are you editing my question?